# Angular multi-level ng-content

Tags: angular, angular-dart

I am using Angular Dart v4 and am attempting to use four components as follows:

```
<!--ComponentA Template-->
<component-a>
    <component-b>
        <component-c></component-c>
    </component-b>
</component-a>

<!--ComponentB Template-->
<component-b>
    <component-d>
        <ng-content></ng-content> <!--component-c-->
    </component-d>
</component-b>
```

In this case, `component-c` is not being compiled in `component-d` via `ng-content` of `component-b`. I have added `component-c` to the directives list of all components.

Is this possible? Let me know if I need to clarify anything since obviously this is oversimplified. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is certainly possible. The template of `component-d` must also have an `<ng-content>` in it. Perhaps that's what's missing? Otherwise could you provide a more detailed reproduction please?